# How to quickly access all values corresponding to a specific second level key regardless of first level key in a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python Dictionary like:

> Mydict =  {'a': {'y': 1, 'x': 5}, 'b': {'y': 10, 'x': 8}}

Is there any quick way to access the values corresponding to the key: 'x',  which in this case is a second level key, regardless of the first level key?

I know it can be done using a for loop like:

```
mylist=[]
for k in Mydict.keys():
    mylist.append(Mydict[k]['x'])
```

But is there any quick one line method for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [list-comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
mylist = [v['x'] for v in Mydict.values()]
```

Since you do not need the outer keys, you just iterate over the inner dicts, and get the desired `'x'` value.

Note: This will only work if each inner dict has an `'x'` key, to be sure, and to minimize errors, you can do this:

```
mylist = [v.get('x', None) for v in Mydict.values()]
```

This will function the same, only if there is no `'x'` key in the dictionary, it will return `None` instead of a `KeyError` exception.

For timing, and to see which method is best, look at the answer by [Thorsten Kranz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703683/1561176)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness: `map` is usually a good alternative to list comprehension, e.g.

```
mylist = map(lambda v: v['x'], Mydict.values())
```

or

```
mylist = map(lambda k: Mydict[k]['x'], Mydict)
```

It's usually up to you what you prefer.

**EDIT:**

As performance came up, here a quick comparison for 1,000,000 repetitions:

```
import timeit

Mydict = {'a': {'y': 1, 'x': 5}, 'b': {'y': 10, 'x': 8}}

def list_append(d):
    mylist=[]
    for k in d.keys():
        mylist.append(d[k]['x'])

def list_comprehension_values(d):
    return [v['x'] for v in d.values()]

def list_comprehension_keys(d):
    return [d[k]['x'] for k in d]

def map_values(d):
    return map(lambda v: v['x'], d.values())

def map_keys(d):    
    return map(lambda k: d[k]['x'], d)

for method_name in ["list_append",
                    "list_comprehension_values",
                    "list_comprehension_keys",
                    "map_values",
                    "map_keys"]:
    t = timeit.timeit(method_name + "(Mydict)",
                      "from __main__ import Mydict, " + method_name, 
                      number=1000000)
    print "%s: %.2f seconds" % (method_name, t)
```

results in:

```
list_append: 0.95 seconds
list_comprehension_values: 0.56 seconds
list_comprehension_keys: 0.47 seconds
map_values: 1.02 seconds
map_keys: 1.01 seconds
```

**Edit 2 **

For a larger dictionary

```
Mydict = dict(zip(range(10000), 
              [{'x' : random.randint(0,10), 'y' : random.randint(0,10)} 
                  for i in range(10000)]))
```

and less repetitions (number=10000), the values are different:

```
list_append: 16.41 seconds
list_comprehension_values: 6.00 seconds
list_comprehension_keys: 9.62 seconds
map_values: 15.23 seconds
map_keys: 18.42 seconds
```

So saving on the key-lookup is better here.

Comment: Preference is important, so is readability, but also speed and efficiency. When iterating over inner dicts you save on lookups which is faster than iterating over keys and then looking them up each time. Also - as in my answer, should probably use `dict.get(key, default)` instead of just accessing it.

Comment: I was surprised as well that accessing the values directly **is not faster** than iterating over the keys and looking the value up each time.

Comment: Well, to counter your argument, this is tested on a very small subset. Given a larger dataset the faster implementation might be different. But I will grant you that with smaller dicts it is probably faster to get a list of keys and then look at small dicts of 1 or 2 values... I hope you see my point that with dicts of hundreds of outer and inner keys it will be much faster to skip the outer dict and go straight in. - And even with the smaller dataset, the difference is not so great as to be 'twice' as fast, as said by others.

Comment: You're right, for larger dictionaries, your approach is faster.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension would be one line, and is almost twice as fast:

```
mylist = [mydict[k]['x'] for k in mydict]
```

Comment: Why is it not quicker? It is quicker AFAIK, please explain?

Comment: We'll it's still O(len(mydict)). The looping overhead is a bit smaller, sure.

Comment: List comprehension is implemented in a much more efficient way than native python. and is much faster, you can check yourself, do not believe me.

Comment: Fine, I got too theoretical.

Comment: List comprehension is twice as fast, and your approach, using keys, is even faster than accessing the values directly - see my test in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension

```
mylist = [Mydict[k]['x'] for k in Mydict]
```

Note that iterating over `Mydict` automatically iterates over the keys, so no need to iterate over `Mydict.keys()`.

Comment: Your approach is the fastest of the proposed options.

Comment: ... but only for small dictionaries