# Accessing Python dict keys with or without dict.keys()

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Usually I access `dict` keys using `keys()` method:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

for k in d.keys(): print k
```

But sometimes I see this code:

```
for k in d: print k
```

Is this code correct? safe?

Comment: See here for timing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14703683/1561176 And for some information on different methods to get information from dicts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this was already mentioned, I wanted to add some exact numbers to these discussion. So I compared:

```
def iter_dtest(dtest):
    for i in dtest:
        pass
```

and

```
def list_dtest(dtest):
    for i in dtest.keys():
        pass
```

A dictionary with 1 000 000 items was used (float keys) and I used `timeit` with 100 repetitions. These are the results:

```
Python 2.7.1:
iter_dtest: 3.92487884435s
list_dtest: 6.24848171448s

Python 3.2.1:
iter_dtest: 3.4850587113842555s
list_dtest: 3.535072302413432s
```

Obviously calling `dtest.keys()` has some downsides in Python 2.x

Comment: The problem with your comparison is that in Python 2 the semantics are completely different: dict.keys() has to allocate and fill a list, whereas iterating (or using dict.iterkeys() or dict.viewkeys()) does not. In Python 3, dict.keys() is a view (~dict.viewkeys()) and so essentially free.

Answer (score 11):

To answer your explicit question, Yes, it is safe.

To answer the question you didn't know you had:

in python 2.x: `dict.keys()` returns a list of keys.

But doing `for k in dict` iterates over them.

Iterating is faster than constructing a list.

in python 3+ explicitly calling `dict.keys()` is not slower because it also returns an iterator.

Most dictionary needs can usually be solved by iterating over the `items()` instead of by keys in the following manner:

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    # k is the key
    # v is the value
    print '%s: %s' % (k, v)
```

Comment: `dict.keys()` returns a `list` on python2.x, but not 3.x, so there could be differences if you change the dict as you iterate over it using `for k in d`, but (on python2.x at least), the ultimate behavior of your dictionary is deterministic for doing certain operations on the dict (e.g. inserting new elements) when iterating over `d.keys()`

Answer (score 3):

The second code example's behaviour is equal to calling `.keys()`, so yes, this is correct and safe.

Comment: More correctly, a dictionary's `__iter__()` method returns an iterator over its keys, and `in d` constructs such an iterator.

Comment: Umm, does it explicitly call `.keys()` or just use the property that a `dict` is iterable over its keys... ie, the diff between `for i in some_iterable` and `for i in some_list`...

Comment: There are some subtle differences (at least on python2.x) where they might not actually lead to the same results.  See my comment on [InbarRose's post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14730599/748858)

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same.

```
for k in d: print k
```

does not create additional list, while

```
for k in d.keys(): print k
```

creates another list and then iterates over it

At least in Python 2. In Python 3 `dict.keys()` is an iterator.

So you can use either `for k in d.iterkeys()` or `for k in d`. Both lead to the same result.